# modal bootstrap cerrar con enter

Tags: bootstrap, modal

tengo el sig modal pero solo se cierra cuando se da click en el boton
tambien quiero que se cierre cuando presioen enter,gracias

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalRetencion" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4> <label style="margin-left:25%;"  id="soyla"></label> </h4>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button style="margin-left:30%;"  type="submit" class="btn btn-danger  pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Aceptar</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-body" >
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes saber cuando un modal se ha mostrado con el evento 'shown.bs.modal', [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) te dejo el enlace para ver los eventos del modal.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

});
```

Una vez que asignes tu evento del DOM, mediante el evento 'keydown' de jQuery puedes saber cuando una tecla fue presionada, el enter tiene un valor númerico de 13, entonces preguntamos por ese valor.

```
$(this).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Y para ocultar el modal simplemente:

```
$('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
```

El código completo sería:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
          $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
        }
      });
    });
});
```

[Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/checosele/esjq87cd/) te dejo el ejemplo completo.